# Counting how many rows are added to table via javascript

Tags: javascript

So im building a table in which the client is allowed to add more rows inorder to add more data to the table.
How can i count the total number of rows that is added to the table?
here is the example which for whatever reason doesn't actually work on jsfiddle, but just to get an idea of the functionality.

http://jsfiddle.net/ScEzz/1/

so say the user adds 5 rows 3 times and 15 rows once, the result should be (5*3)15+15 +original 1 = 31

Comment: I think if you actually implement the adding of the rows it will become quite clear how to count the number of rows added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to keep track in your code, but aside from that, you can do this...

```
var count = document.getElementbyId("mytable").rows.length;
```

---

Or with jQuery if you want...

```
var count = $("#mytable > tr").length;
```

Comment: Thank you, i was banging my head for the past hour! once 7 minutes is up, you got the best answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#mytable tr").length-1
```

This gets you teh number of `tr`s minus 1 for the header.

Since you're already using jQuery, you can make the code a cleaner by doing some things in jQuery instead of JS.

- Select elements with `$('#mytable');`
- Create an element with just a begin tag in jQuery: `var row = $('<tr>');`
- Use jQuery's append method `table.append(row);`

Comment: Even better, move the header into a thead and count the rows in the tbody. Less variables that way, just in case a second header row would be added, etc.

Comment: Thank you guys, this solution works great, but am not i am beat ya too it